# jQuery function doesn't hide section

Tags: jquery

I'm using a function to hide empty containers, but it does not work on one section.

Here is the code:

```
$( '.lmla-hidden' ).each(function() {
      if ( '' === $.trim( $( this ).text() ) ) {
        $( this ).hide();
      }
    });
```

This is where it is being applied:

```
<section class="section-wrapper-projects lmla-hidden">

          <h2 class="section-title lmla-hidden"><?php echo CFS()->get('course_details_title_project'); ?></h2>

          <div class="projects-description lmla-hidden">
                        <?php echo CFS()->get('design_cycle'); ?>
                    </div>

          <div class="single-project-wrapper lmla-hidden">
                        <p class="project-title lmla-hidden"><?php echo CFS()->get('project_title'); ?></p>

                        <div class="project-image lmla-hidden"><img src="<?php echo CFS()->get('project_image'); ?>"></div>

                        <style> .project-link-btn a {color: <?php echo CFS()->get('link_text_colour'); ?>;} </style>
                        <style> .project-link-btn {background: <?php echo CFS()->get('project_link_colour'); ?>;} </style>

                        <div class="project-link-btn lmla-hidden"><?php echo CFS()->get('projects_link'); ?></div>

                    </div>

      </section>
```

The padding-bottom property is still being applied to the section.

Comment: `lmla-hidden` there are so many elements with class `lmla-hidden` can you specify which character do you refer to?

Comment: just put a debugger inside function, and try to figure out why the text is not empty, do it yourself first.

Comment: Specifically, it's the section class"section-wrapper-projects". All the other elements hide when lmla-hidden is applied to them, only the section retains its properties. I thought it might have something to do with the function being unable to hide sections.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that everything is working.

```js
$('.lmla-hidden').each(function() {
  if (!$.trim($(this).text())) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.project-link-btn a {
  color: red;
  background: black;
}

.project-link-btn {
  background: black;
}

.lmla-hidden {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="section-wrapper-projects lmla-hidden">

  <h2 class="section-title lmla-hidden">Test</h2>

  <div class="projects-description lmla-hidden">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
  </div>
  
  <div class="projects-description lmla-hidden">
    <!-- An empty element will be hidden -->
  </div>

  <div class="single-project-wrapper lmla-hidden">
    <p class="project-title lmla-hidden">
      Test
    </p>

    <div class="project-image lmla-hidden"><img src="some-img.jpg"></div>

    <div class="project-link-btn lmla-hidden">
      <a href="#">qwerty</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```